# Add custom field to cart item

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom field to each item that I am manually adding to the cart. The custom field is a print ID that is passed back from a third party API.

This needs to be attached to each item in the cart so they can be used once the order has been paid for.

I am trying setting the custom field for each cart item using $cart_item_data when manually adding to the cart. I am not sure if this is what I need to do but god loves a trier :)

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, '', '', array(printJobId => 12345) );
```

When I view the order in woocommerce I cant see the printJobId anywhere.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: how are you trying to view the printJobId field? It wont display anywhere by default, you will need to display it manually somewhere

Comment: is the printJobId field being set in the database when you order an item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two other hook :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session',  'cart_item_from_session' , 99, 2 );

function cart_item_from_session( $data, $values ) {
    $data[ 'printJobId' ] = isset( $values[ 'printJobId' ] ) ? $values[ 'printJobId' ] : '';
    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_item_meta_order', 10, 3 );

function add_item_meta_order( $item_id, $values ) {
    if ( !is_null( $values[ 'printJobId' ] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'printJobId', $values[ 'printJobId' ] );
    }
}
```

Then you will see the meta data on the backoffice and also on the order-details page